# Java Abstract class errors

Tags: java, abstract, super

I'm trying to understand why I'm getting the errors I'm getting involving abstract classes.

I have an abstract class **Token**, a class **AddToken** which extends **Token** and a class **ExpressionTokenizer** which creates an **AddToken** object.

**AddToken** gets:

```
"Error: AddToken is not abstract and does not override abstract method compareTo(java.lang.Object) in java.lang.Comparable"
```

So I make AddToken abstract

Then ExpressionTokenizer gets:

```
Error: AddToken is abstract; cannot be instantiated
```

So, what are my options? I don't understand the last error, and I have no reason to override the method in Token.

This is for a class, and there are a lot more classes, but I never learned super, so I'm learning as I go on this....

Token

```
abstract class Token implements Comparable
{
  private char tokenCode;     // the token code as specified above
  private String lexeme;      // the lexeme for the particular token
  private int prePrecedence,  
    postPrecedence; 
  /* These values are used for comparing precendences
   of two tokens
   */

  /*
   Constructor for a Token with all attributes specified - to
   be used by subclass constructors to construct tokens with
   appropriate values
   */      
  public Token(char tknCode, String lexeem, int prePrec, int postPrec)
  {
    tokenCode = tknCode;
    lexeme = lexeem;
    prePrecedence = prePrec;
    postPrecedence = postPrec;
  }

  // Returns the lexem for the token
  public String getLexeme()
  {
    return lexeme;
  }

  // Returns the token code
  public char getTokenCode()
  {
    return tokenCode;
  }

  /*
   Compares the current token (receiver) to the given token
   for precedence: -1 denotes that receiver yields precedence,
   0 denotes equal precedence, and 1 denotes that receiver takes
   precendence.
   */
  public int CompareTo(Token tok)
  {
    if (this.prePrecedence < tok.postPrecedence)
      return -1;
    else if (this.prePrecedence == tok.postPrecedence)
      return 0;
    else // this.prePrecedence > tok.postPrecedence
      return 1;
  }
}
```

AddToken (non abstract)

```
class AddToken extends Token
{
 public AddToken()
 {
    super( 'A', "+", 4, 3 );
 }

}
```

ExpressionTokenizer

```
class ExpressionTokenizer
{
  String expression;
  //The expression as a string

  int lexicalPointer,
    //Index of the first character of lexeme
    forwardPointer;
  //Index of the current character of lexeme

  public ExpressionTokenizer(String expr)
    /* Initialize tokenizer for the given expression.
     Set lexical pointer to the first character of the first lexeme.
     */
  {
    expression = expr;
    lexicalPointer = 0;
    skipWhiteSpace();
  }


  private void skipWhiteSpace()
    // Move the lexical pointer through the spaces and tabs between tokens.
  {
    while (lexicalPointer < expression.length() && 
           (expression.charAt(lexicalPointer) == ' ' || 
            expression.charAt(lexicalPointer) == '\t') )
    {
      lexicalPointer++;   
    }
  }

  private boolean isNotFinal(int state)
    /* The finite state machine has only two non-final states.
     This is a result of having the lexeme for all but one token 
     (NumberToken) be only one character long.
     */
  {
    return state == 0 || state == 1;
  }

  public Token getToken() throws InvalidCharacterException
    // Return the next token in the expression using a finite state machine
  {
    Token returnToken = null; 

    int state = 0;  //Starting state for the finite state machine

    forwardPointer = lexicalPointer;

    // The loop implements the finite state machine
    while (forwardPointer < expression.length()
             && isNotFinal(state)){

      char currentChar = expression.charAt(forwardPointer);

      switch (state){

        case 0: if (Character.isDigit(currentChar))
          state = 1;
        else
        {
          switch (currentChar)
          {
            case '+': state = 3; break;
            case '-': state = 4; break;
            case '*': state = 5; break;
            case '/': state = 6; break;
            case '%': state = 7; break;
            case '(': state = 8; break;
            case ')': state = 9; break;
            case '=': state = 10; break;
            default:  throw new InvalidCharacterException(currentChar);
          } // inner switch
        } //else
        break;

        case 1: if (Character.isDigit(currentChar))
          state = 1;
        else
          state = 2;
        break;
      }  // outer switch

      forwardPointer++;
    } // while

    // Determine returnToken based on final state
    if (state == 2){
      // forwardPointer advanced two characters beyond end of lexeme
      forwardPointer--;
      String lexeme = expression.substring(lexicalPointer,forwardPointer);
      returnToken = new NumberToken(lexeme);
    }
    else{

      switch (state){
        case 3: returnToken = new AddToken(); break;
        case 4: returnToken = new SubtractToken(); break;
        case 5: returnToken = new MultiplyToken(); break;
        case 6: returnToken = new DivideToken(); break;
        case 7: returnToken = new ModToken(); break; 
        case 8: returnToken = new LeftParenToken(); break;
        case 9: returnToken = new RightParenToken(); break;
        case 10: returnToken = new EqualSignToken(); break;
      } // switch
    } // else

    // Advance lexicalPointer to next token and return current token
    lexicalPointer = forwardPointer;
    skipWhiteSpace();
    return returnToken;

  } // getToken

  public boolean isEndOfExpression()
  {
    return lexicalPointer == expression.length();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Token` class is implementing the raw form of the `Comparable` interface, which expects a `compareTo(Object)` method.

There is no need to make it `abstract`.  Implement the generic form instead:

```
//                               vvvvvvv
class Token implements Comparable<Token>
```

Also, the method should be called "compareTo", lowercase "c", to match [the interface method name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29).

```
//         v--- lowercase
public int compareTo(Token tok)
```

Using the `@Override` annotation on the method can also help catch these kinds of errors, where a method you think is overriding or implementing something isn't really overriding or implementing anything.

Comment: It's not even quite doing that - it's got a method called `CompareTo`, not `compareTo`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Good catch.  I had just done a "find" on the page for "compareTo" and found the case-insensitive match.  I didn't even notice the capital "C".